# How to properly keep reference to an object used by an ActionSheet delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I frequently face a situation where I have a reference to an object.

I have to ask user what to do with it with an UIActionSheet.

So I use that action sheet, but after user tap a row, I have the user willings, but no reference to the object.

I usually use a property in my view controller to keep a reference to the object, but I find this design really poor...

Is there any way to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you associate your UIActionSheet instance with the object using `objc_setAssociatedObject` and then retrieve the object in your UIActionSheet delegate method with `objc_getAssociatedObject`.

Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getAssociatedObject

Comment: Thanks that was the kind of design I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your implementation and what kind of data you have in your object, but you can use Singleton design pattern, create a shared instance and do any required operations in UIActionSheet delegate methods.

Comment: I have multiple objects in an Array, and one was selected by the user.
I ask him what to with it and i want a reference to the object at runtime in the action sheet delegate.